# How to convert text to an image in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I want to show some content as an image instead of html e.g I want to show phone number of users as an image.

But how can I convert that text to an image in rails? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution that comes to mind is to use a web service for this – e.g. https://textoverimage.moesif.com/. But based on your description, I assume that one of the reasons you're looking for such a solution is privacy concerns – so sharing a phone number with a 3rd party web service wouldn't seem to be the right way to go.

The next best thing would be to use ImageMagick to simply draw text on an image that is created on the fly. The RMagick library allows for pretty direct integration of Ruby and ImageMagick. The usage page (https://rmagick.github.io/usage.html#drawing_on) includes examples on how to draw text onto an image. You can then just call the image's `to_blob` method and use Rails' `send_data` to send the image. The resulting code would look something like the following (note that I'm making a bunch of assumptions regarding your data model which may or may not be true):

```rb
class PhoneNumbersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :png, only: :show

  def show
    phone_number = PhoneNumber.find(params[:phone_number_id])

    canvas = Magick::ImageList.new("number.png")
    text = phone_number.full_number # or whatever your full representation method is called
    # ... add the rest of the code based on the RMagick examples mentioned above

    send_data(canvas.to_blob, type: :png, disposition: :inline)
  end
end
```